# Powershell loop, with sqlplus connection string

Tags: powershell, loops, scripting, sqlplus

I want to create a power shell script, that loops a connection string using sqlplus but i am not really sure how to do it in power shell.

something like:

```
begin
  for i in 1..10
  loop
    sqlplus .../...@'(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=...)(HOST=...)(PORT=...)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=...)))
    --- wait for response then move foreward
  end loop;
end
```

The idea is that i want to test different connection_timeout values in the connection string to determine which value is more stable.

I have found this piece of powershell code online, but i am not sure how to adjust it for my requirement:

```
$lines = Get-Content 'c:\firstsecondnames.txt'
$DBs = "192.168.1.1"
$DB = "DBA"
$ConnectionTimeout = 90
$QueryTimeout = 90

foreach ($line in $lines) {
    $vala  = $line.Split(',')[0]
    $valb  = $line.Split(',')[1]
    #DB query
    $Query = "select ValC from dbo.PROCESSED_INTERCHANGES where Firstname = '$vala' and middlename = '$valb'"
    $conn=new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection
    $ConnectionString = "Server={0};Database={1};Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout={2}" -f $DBs,$DB,$ConnectionTimeout
    $conn.ConnectionString=$ConnectionString
    $conn.Open()
    $cmd=new-object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Query,$conn)
    $cmd.CommandTimeout=$QueryTimeout
    $ds=New-Object system.Data.DataSet
    $da=New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)
    [void]$da.fill($ds)
    $conn.Close()
    $conn.Dispose()
    foreach ($valC in $ds.tables[0].rows.ValC) {
        $fullname = $vala + $valb + $valC
      Write-Host $fullname
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to test various connection_timeout values, you should loop over these values instead of loping over a set of user FirstNames and MiddleNames.

Something like this:

```
$DBs = "192.168.1.1"
$DB  = "DBA"
# insert working values here. We don't test these, we only try out different ConnectionTimeouts
$vala  = 'FirstName'
$valb  = 'MiddleName'
$QueryTimeout = 90
# try a range of connection timeout values. For demo here 10, 20 .. 200 + 0
$ConnectionTimeout = for ($i = 10; $i -le 200; $i += 10) { $i }
# lastly, add 'Infinite' value 0
$ConnectionTimeout += 0

$ConnectionTimeout | ForEach-Object {
    # show what timeout value is now in effect
    Write-Host $(switch ($_){
        0       { "Attempting Infinite timeout $_" ; break}
        30      { "Attempting Default timeout $_"  ; break }
        default { "Attempting timeout $_" }
    }) -ForegroundColor Cyan
    #DB query
    $Query = "select ValC from dbo.PROCESSED_INTERCHANGES where Firstname = '$vala' and middlename = '$valb'"
    $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection
    $ConnectionString = "Server={0};Database={1};Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout={2}" -f $DBs, $DB, $_
    $conn.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
    $conn.Open()
    $cmd = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($Query,$conn)
    $cmd.CommandTimeout = $QueryTimeout
    $ds = New-Object system.Data.DataSet
    $da = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter($cmd)
    [void]$da.fill($ds)
    foreach ($valC in $ds.tables[0].rows.ValC) {
        $fullname = $vala + $valb + $valC
        Write-Host $fullname
    }
    # clean-up
    $conn.Close()
    $conn.Dispose()
    $ds.Dispose()
    $da.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: Thank, i will try this structure, but in order to check which value is stable basically i need to loop the connection string to infinite (break manually). I can change the timeout values manually

Comment: @gavagio I have edited the answer to include a new timeout scheme including Infinite